# how to package a user selected folder for upload using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, zip

I have a "file browser" website where the user can browse files and folders located on a remote file server. I need to allow the user to upload entire directories along with the subdirectories. The only method I've heard of that works is to zip the folder. How can I zip a directory that the user selects using javascript?
Right now the user selects a folder using the form element I just need to be able to zip the selected folder along with its contents.

I've seen references to using JSzip or client-zip among others. However, no one mentions how to reference the selected folder. Most suggestions specify the folder by name instead of the directory path.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I've found the solution. When using the HTML form element to select a directory for upload, the data stores the path relative to the subdirectory ie "folderNamebeingUploaded/subdir". Using this you can use the PHP "mkdir('dirname')" to construct the directories and use the forward slashes as delimiters.

Here is the HTML:

```html
<form action="uploadDirectory.php" name="myForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  Type Folder Name:<input type="text" name="foldername" /><br/><br/>
  Select Folder to Upload: <input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple directory="" webkitdirectory="" moxdirectory="" /><br/><br/> 
  <input type="Submit" value="Upload" name="upload" id="uploadFolder" />
  </form>
```

And here is the PHP file that's on the server:

```php
<?php
foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name)
{
    echo $name . "<br>";
    
    $rel = $_FILES['files']['full_path'][$i];

    $rootDir = "/home/ankle/fileBrowserShare/";
    $relativeDir = "";

    //trimming the extra backslash
    if(substr($rel, 0, strpos($rel, "/") + 1) == "/"){
        $rel = substr($rel, strpos($rel, "/") + 1, strlen($rel));
    }
    //constructing the relative path
    while(substr_count($rel, strval("/")) > 0)
    {
        $subDir = substr($rel, 0, strpos($rel, "/") + 1);
        $rel = substr($rel, strpos($rel, "/") + 1, strlen($rel));
        $relativeDir = $relativeDir . $subDir;

        if(strlen($subDir) == 1){
            continue;
        }
        else if(!is_dir($rootDir . $relativeDir)){
            mkdir($rootDir . $relativeDir);
            chmod($rootDir . $relativeDir, 0777);

        }
    }
    //moving the actual file to this destination
    //scanning through each subdir
    
    if(strlen($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]) > 1)
    {
        echo "File length reasonable ";
        echo $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i],$rootDir . $relativeDir .$name;
        echo move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i],$rootDir . $relativeDir .$name) . "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

One thing to note is that you may run into a caching issue with creating and removing directories in Ubuntu that may result in false positives when checking if a directory or file exists.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Also, I wanted to point out that comments and answers are being removed without my knowledge. I recently had a decent conversation with others on this topic in the comments, brainstorming ideas to solve this issue and now those comments are gone.